# Problema en llamada a una función de eliminar elementos de un vector

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

He creado dos funciones para eliminar un elemento de un vector: la primera es la que borra el elemento de la posición pasada por parámetro y llama a la primera para borrar aquel elemento que sea menor que otro.

Cuando intento llamar a la primera me da error, y no entiendo por qué.
Código de struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define N 20

struct Tpunto                   // punto en un plano, x abscisas, y ordenadas
{
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct Tcirculo                 //Circulo: punto central y longitud del radio
{
    struct Tpunto centro;
    float radio;
};

struct TlistaPuntos            //Lista de puntos del plano
{
    int tam;                      //cantidad de valores en el vector puntos
    struct Tpunto puntos[N];
};

struct TlistaCirculos          //Lista de circulos
{
    int tam;                      //cantidad de valores en el vector circulos
    struct Tcirculo circulos[N];
};
```

Código main y funciones:

```
void main()
{
    struct TlistaCirculos lisC = {3,{{{5, 6}, 1.4},{{15, 16}, 11.4},{{-3, 6}, 9.4}}};
    float radioC=7;

    eliminar_circulo(&lisC, radioC);
    escribir_circulos(lisC);
}

void eliminar_posicion(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, int pos)
{
    int i;
    for(i=pos; i<listaC->tam-1; i++)
        listaC[i]=listaC[i+1];
    listaC->tam--;
}

void eliminar_circulo(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, float radio)
{
    int i, pos;
    for(pos=0; pos<listaC->tam; pos++)
    {
        if(listaC->circulos[pos].radio > radio)
        {
            eliminar_posicion(&listaC, pos);
        }
    }
}
```

La función de escribir_circulos esta correcta porque la he probado en otro programa, ¿por qué no funciona la función que elimina?  Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No estoy seguro de lo que estas haciendo, solo di un vistazo rápido pero parece que tratas a `TlistaCirculos *listaC` como un arreglo cuando tratas de borrar cuando no lo es, tal vez lo que buscas es

```
void eliminar_posicion(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, int pos)
{
    int i;
    for(i=pos; i<listaC->tam-1; i++)
       listaC->circulos[i]=listaC->circulos[i+1];
       listaC->tam--;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void eliminar_posicion(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, int pos);

void eliminar_circulo(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, float radio)
{
  eliminar_posicion(&listaC, pos);
}
```

En el código anterior he eliminado todo lo redundante para centrarme en el foco del error.

La función `eliminar_posicion` espera recibir un puntero de tipo `TlistaCirculos`. En `eliminar_circulo` tienes `listaC`, que es un puntero de tipo `TlistaCirculos` y al llamar a `eliminar_posicion` le pasas una referencia a `listaC`, es decir, le estás pasando un puntero doble. Lo que sucede después te lo puedes imaginar.

La solución es tan sencilla como quitar esa referencia:

```
void eliminar_circulo(struct TlistaCirculos *listaC, float radio)
{
  eliminar_posicion(listaC, pos);
}
```

Las referencias las debes utilizar únicamente cuando necesitas añadir un nivel de indirección:

- tienes una variable y la función necesita un puntero simple
- tienes un puntero simple y te hace falta un puntero doble
- ...

Por otro lado, en este bucle:

```
for(i=pos; i<listaC->tam-1; i++)
    listaC[i]=listaC[i+1];
```

Si `listaC->tam` es igual a `N`, es decir, la lista está llena, el código anterior intentará hacer `lista[N-1]=lista[N]`. Teniendo en cuenta que los índices del arreglo van de 0 a N te puedes imaginar que `lista[N]` intenta acceder a memoria que no pertenece al arreglo lo cual es peligroso porque puedes provocar un casque en tu aplicación.

Y bueno, para rematar una sugerencia: desde el estándar C99, que data de 1999 (del siglo pasado nada menos), es posible declarar las variables de iteración dentro del propio bucle:

```
for(int i=pos; i<listaC->tam-1; i++)
    listaC[i]=listaC[i+1];
```

La ventaja de hacerlo así es que la variable se pierde al finalizar el bucle, lo que puede evitar problemas relacionados con la reutilización de variables.

Un saludo.